# Modification of .bash_history file

Tags: shell

my .bash_history file is saved in this format:

#1674818484

conda install netcdf4

#1674818558

conda list

#1674818583

conda install matplotlib

#1674819525

conda install cdo

#1674819584

conda list

#1674819634

conda install proj4

The numbers are seconds count by 1970. But, because this is not always practical, I want to be stored in .bash_history **both the time in UTC and seconds from 1970**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get both UTC and time since the epoch in the history file. However, you can add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T %Z "
```

Which will store the time in a more readable format. If you want both values, your best option may be a custom script that parses your epoch seconds and converts to UTC time.

Comment: Although this command (and other commants) change what is printed with the command history, I still can interfere with the .bash_history. It continues to print out epoch time.